# Module not found - importing React navbar class...but the file exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It cannot find my navbar.js file for some reason, but its there!? Any help is appreciated
Just keeps showing -

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/App.js 5:0-41

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/navbar' in 'C:\Users\ekrus\OneDrive\Desktop\honeycomb\honeycomb\client\src'
```

The navbar.js file:

```
import React from 'React';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

export default class Navbar extends React.Component {
     render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul className="nav">
                <li className="nav-item slam-left"><a href="#">Brand</a></li>
                <li className="nav-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li className="nav-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li className="nav-item"><a className="contact" href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
    );
}
```

}

My App.js file:

```
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/navbar';

function App() {
  return (
      <Navbar />
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: [Please post code as formatted text rather than links to images of formatted text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Ok added them as code snippets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `navbar.js` you are exporting your component as a named export, and in your `App.js` you are trying to do a default import, which doesn't exist.

change your navbar component to start with `export default class Navbar`...

You can read more about named and default exports [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)
and [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/understanding-the-difference-between-named-and-default-exports-in-react-2d253ca9fc22#:%7E:text=Combining,both%20default%20and%20named%20components.)

Edit: After looking at the directory structure again, seems like you have the path of the `navbar` file off. The `Navbar` is in `components/navbar/navbar`.

so you should change your import statement to

```
import Navbar from "./componenets/navbar/navbar";
```

Edit 2:
I also noticed that in `App.js` you imported react from React, and it needs to be `react`, with a lowercase R.
change it to:

```
import React from 'react';
```

Comment: Sorry, this didnt change anything, changing it to 'export default class Navbar'

Comment: checkout my edit

Comment: wait, ok. So I misspelled components after your change. This worked for this error, now its saying a new error: OR in ./src/components/navbar/navbar.js 4:0-26
Module not found: Error: Cannot find file: 'index.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: '.\node_modules\React\react'.

Comment: Could you show your directory structure again? For some reason your program can't find your navbar.js file

Comment: could you Provide the folder structure

Comment: Are the components and App.js in the src folder and same level

Comment: when you imported react you imported it from 'React', it need to be 'react', with lower case R

Comment: @EricKrusznis look at my 2nd edit

Comment: Thank you all!
yes the 'React' change to 'react' fixed my issue!